# Apache Camel aggregator in combination with onCompletion

Tags: apache-camel

I want the onCompletion to occur after all the aggregated exchanges triggered by both completion size followed by timeout are processed. But it occurs right after the completion size is triggered with some of the exchanges waiting to be triggered by the timeout criteria.

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking. Could you provide some sample code that reproduces the problem and explain what you expect to happen.

Comment: Are you saying that you have specified multiple completion conditions, and the aggregated output message is triggered when EITHER completion condition is met. Instead, you want it triggered if BOTH completion conditions are met. Is that right?

Comment: Since my clarification is too big for a comment , I did it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

I have the route configured as

from(fromEndPoint)
    .onCompletion()
    .doSomething()
    .split() // each Line
    .streaming()
    .parallelProcessing()
    .unmarshal().bindy
    .aggregate()
    .completionSize(100)
    .completionTimeout(5000)
    .to(toEndpoint)

Assume if the split was done on 405 lines, the first 4 sets of aggregated exchanges go to the to endpoint completing 400 lines(exchanges) . And then, it immediately triggers the onCompletion. But there are still 5 more aggregated exchanges which would be triggered when the completionTimeout criteria is met. It didn't trigger the onCompletion after the 5 exchanges are routed to the to endpoint.

My question here is , either the onCompletion should be triggered for each exchange or once after all.

Note:- My from endpoint here is a File.

Comment: did you found solution to this ?

Comment: Ditto. This must be a common "problem", that i'm wondering if Camel is the right thing to be using for this use case.